# prints the number of occurances of the second string within the first string's comma-separated members

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

Write a program that takes in:

s1 A comma-separated string
s2 A string to be counted
And prints the number of occurances of the second string within the first string's comma-separated members.

For example, if the user inputs one, two, one, three and then one, your program should print 2. Hint: You'll find the method list.count() helpful here. The input() statements and associated string processing you should use have been provided in the example code below. (Note: assume that each comma in the user-inputted series is followed by a single space.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
# split on comma + space to create the list
s1= input('Please enter a series of comma-separated strings: ')
# split on comma + space to create the list
1 = s1.split(', ')
# input the string to count in the list
s2 = input('Please enter a string to count: ')
# print out the number of times s2 occurs in s1
print(list.count(s2))
```

I was given an example of what they were looking for, but still not understanding the concept completely. Here is what they gave me: "For example, if the user inputs one, two, one, three and then one, your program should print 2. Hint: You'll find the method list.count() helpful here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues of note here:

- With `1 = s1.split(', ')`, you're assigning the returning value of `split` to a number `1`. You should assign it to a valid variable name such as `l` instead.
- Typically a comma-separated list means a string of items separated by just commas, not including a space, so you should split by `','` instead of `', '`.
- With `print(list.count(s2))`, you're calling the `list.count` method as an unbound method, but since you're trying to count the occurrence of `s2` in `l`, you should call it as a bound method to `l` instead, as in `l.count(s2)`.

With the above modifications, your code should look like:

```
s1= input('Please enter a series of comma-separated strings: ')
l = s1.split(',')
s2 = input('Please enter a string to count: ')
print(l.count(s2))
```

Sample input/output:

```
Please enter a series of comma-separated strings: one,two,three,one
Please enter a string to count: one
2
```